# How can I open Windows Explorer to select a folder path with a nicer layout , for example, in image below?

Tags: excel, vba

I use this code to user choose a folder path, I don't know if a should create a user form.

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
  If .Show = -1 Then
    FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
  End If
End With
```

[image]

I would like this:

[image]

Comment: You don't like the UI of the folder browser shown by that code? On which operating system?

Comment: Windows Vista. The image is just a example, nothing about contents. Only the external part.

Comment: Sorry - I'm on Win7 and mine looks quite different. It's not really clear from your question though exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Check **[FileDialog Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa433413(v=office.12).aspx)** for things you can alter.

Comment: The one you want looks like the outlook browser - do you want to browse folders in outlook?  If not, then the Shell version looks a little similar: http://wsh2.uw.hu/ch12f.html

Comment: Hi, Tim, thank you. This link will help me!